# Override asBoolean for Number in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Is there any way I can redefine asBoolean for core class in Groovy? I tried

`Number.metaClass.asBoolean = {false}`

While it works for non-Groovy classes I can't find how to make the same trick for Number or any other predefined class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem when executing the script in the GroovyConsole. However, when executed as a `.groovy` file on the command line, the metaClass change works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just missing a `->`. This works for me

```
Number.metaClass.asBoolean = {-> false}
assert !2.asBoolean()  // Normally 2 evaluates to true
```

Comment: @tim_yates but if you omit the `->` then surely you'd be overloading (rather than overriding) the `asBoolean()` method defined by Groovy with a method `asBoolean(Object obj)`

Comment: Seems to work either way for me... (assuming I do `Integer.metaClass`, rather than `Number.metaClass`)